# Would the Standard Model allow two energetic photons to form a particle-like, zero-spin resonance?

Tags: standard-model, higgs

The title is the question: Would the Standard Model allow two energetic photons to form a particle-like, zero-spin resonance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Neutral pions do it all the time. Look for 2-gamma decay of the $\pi^0$. Here's a quick article to get you started: http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1375 And if a neutral pion can decay into two photons, then the opposite reaction is also possible.

Comment: Nice answer and reference, thanks! This is of the positives of Stack Exchange: It's unlikely I would ever have found or recognized the relevance of that particular paper to my question by using only keyword searches. Again, thanks.

Comment: Try: http://www.bing.com/search?q=two+photon+decay+site%3Aarxiv.org&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=two+photon+decay+site%3Aarxiv.org&sc=8-0&sp=-1&sk=